# Compiling powershell scripts using PowerGUI

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, powergui

In my power shell script(**task_scheduler.ps1**) when runs in a system, it creates a daily task in task scheduler. This daily task is to run another power shell file (**action.ps1**) in the system.

Now I would like to convert **task_scheduler.ps1** into an exe file. Since this file accesses **action.ps1** file, I tried giving the same as "dependency" in Power GUI (while compiling script).

Now, the task is getting scheduled. But the task is not running the **action.ps1** file. As the file is not present in the specified path.

How shall I get the path whether the dependency ps1 files get saved?

Comment: Try to open the exe using zip tool  (it's really a zip file) and be sure that all dependent files are available.

Comment: @M.Hassan I tried using zip. But i couldnt find action.ps1 file

Comment: you can add manually using zip tool the action.ps1. I hope it work.